# Failing to associate load balancer with target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-elb

I'm using Terraform to deploy my infrastructure and I keep running into the following error:

```
Error: InvalidParameterException: The target group with targetGroupArn [snip] does
not have an associated load balancer.
```

There is [another question here on SO where the poster is running into a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53971873/the-target-group-does-not-have-an-associated-load-balancer). One of the answers quotes the AWS docs:

> The Amazon ECS service requires an explicit dependency on the
> Application Load Balancer listener rule and the Application Load
> Balancer listener. This prevents the service from starting before the
> listener is ready.

This is basically saying that I should create my listener and listener rule before my service. However, in my listener I'm specifying the target group of my service as the default action:

```
resource "aws_alb_listener" "app_http" {
  load_balancer_arn = module.alb_app.arn
  port              = 80
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = module.app_service.lb_target_group.id
    type             = "forward"
  }
}
```

So, I'm confused on how I can set the `target_group_arn` on the listener if the listener is supposed to be created before my service and target group.

This is how I create my service and its corresponding target group:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
  ...

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.service.arn
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group" "service" {
  ...

  port        = 8080
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  target_type = "ip"
}
```

Comment: Why do you create the target group outside of the module? Have you tried moving it in the module? Also, check whether ```module.app_service.lb_target_group.id``` actually gives you the arn and not something else

Answer (score 3):

As that [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53981427/2291321) suggests, you need to set the dependency on the listener of the load balancer.

With your current code Terraform will see a dependency chain that looks like this (hit run on the snippet to see the dependency graph):

```js
mermaid.initialize({startOnLoad:true});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mermaid@8.0.0/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>

<div class="mermaid">
graph TD
    A[aws_alb_listener.app_http] --> B[module.alb_app.arn]
    A[aws_alb_listener.app_http] --> C[module.app_service.lb_target_group.id]
    D[aws_ecs_service.service] --> C*[aws_alb_target_group.service.arn]

</div>
```

Your error is complaining that when it tries to create/update the service to use the target group that the target group is not yet attached to a load balancer because the target group has yet to be attached to the listener rule or the listener rule is yet to be attached to the load balancer (most likely this as ALB creation is much slower than target group creation and the listener needs to wait for the ALB and the target group to be created before it can be created).

Normally you'd solve this by telling the `aws_ecs_service` resource that it must also depend on the listener or listener rule creation to be complete using the [`depends_on` meta argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/depends_on.html) like this:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
  ...

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.service.arn
  }

  # We need to wait until the target group is attached to the listener
  # and also the load balancer so we wait until the listener creation
  # is complete first
  depends_on = [aws_alb_listener.app_http]
}
```

Which, with a simpler non module layout, would look something like this:

```js
mermaid.initialize({startOnLoad:true});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mermaid@8.0.0/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>

<div class="mermaid">
graph TD
    A[aws_alb_listener.app_http] --> B[aws_alb.app.arn]
    A[aws_alb_listener.app_http] --> C[aws_alb_target_group.service.arn]
    D[aws_ecs_service.service] --> C[aws_alb_target_group.service.arn]
    D[aws_ecs_service.service] -->|depends_on| A[aws_alb_listener.app_http]

</div>
```

It looks like you have an overly complex module layout that I'd probably suggest against and is hard to tell exactly what the address is going to be for your incomplete code that you've provided but if the listener is in a module called `app_lb_listener` then you'd want to depend on `module.app_lb_listener.aws_alb_listener.app_http`.

Comment: The complex module layout is because both my staging and production environment have different listeners. It seems that I have to revert to Terraform `count` (conditional resource strategy) to make this work...

Comment: It's still doable with your module layout (I think, hard to tell without the question including all of your code as an [mcve]) as mentioned in the last paragraph but it does look to me like it's overly complex and you could simplify a lot of it by flattening your module unless there's a good reason to have such a complex nesting of modules.

Answer (score 2):

Your `aws_alb_target_group` should have dependency on your load balancer as there is no direct reference between the two:

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "service" {
  ...

  port        = 8080
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  target_type = "ip"

  depends_on = [aws_alb.ecs-load-balancer]

}
```

where `aws_alb.ecs-load-balancer` should be replaced by your load balancer resource.

Comment: Hmm. OK. So I tried that but unfortunately I still seem to get the same error... In the Terraform output I can see that it is trying to create the ECS service but after 2 minutes it times out with this error. When I inspect the AWS console, I can see that the load balancer has been created. Looking ECS, my app service has not been created... :(

Comment: @Luke There is github issue for that problem. Can you try one of the solutions proposed there, like [this one](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12634#issuecomment-321633155)?