# aws cdk - a target group that targets a container

Tags: python, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, amazon-elb, aws-fargate

I have a `CfnTaskDefinition` with a `container_definitions` property and `requires_compatibilities=['FARGATE']`. A `Cluster`, a `CfnService`, a CfnLoadBalancer with `type='application'`, a `CfnTargetGroup`.
How do I set a listener for the target group with port 80, and a target that targets the container I defined, to port 8080?

my code:

```
app_cluster = _ecs.Cluster(self, 'Cluster', cluster_name='app-cluster', vpc=default_vpc)

app_env_vars = [
            _ecs.CfnTaskDefinition.KeyValuePairProperty(
                name='API_ENABLED',
                value='true'
            )]

app_container_definitions = [
            _ecs.CfnTaskDefinition.ContainerDefinitionProperty(
                name='container-name',
                image='ubuntu:20',
                repository_credentials=_ecs.CfnTaskDefinition.RepositoryCredentialsProperty(
                    credentials_parameter="arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:2222243:secret:prod/credentials-TTR3d"),
                essential=True,
                cpu=0,
                memory=1024,
                memory_reservation=1024,
                log_configuration=_ecs.CfnTaskDefinition.LogConfigurationProperty(
                    log_driver='awslogs',
                    options={'awslogs-stream-prefix': 'ecs',
                             'awslogs-group': app_log_group.log_group_name,
                             'awslogs-region': 'eu-west-1'},
                ),
                port_mappings=[
                    _ecs.CfnTaskDefinition.PortMappingProperty(
                        container_port=8080,
                        host_port=8080,
                        protocol='tcp'
                    )],
                environment=app_env_vars)]

app_task_definition = _ecs.CfnTaskDefinition(self, 'TaskDefinition',
                                                             family='task-prod',
                                                             memory='2048',
                                                             network_mode='awsvpc',
                                                             requires_compatibilities=['FARGATE'],
                                                             execution_role_arn=role_ecs_task.role_arn,
                                                             cpu='512',
                                                             tags=[aws_cdk.CfnTag(
                                                                 key='Environment',
                                                                 value='prod'
                                                             )],
                                                             container_definitions=app_container_definitions)

app_target_group = _elbv2.CfnTargetGroup(self, 'TargetGroup',
                                                         name='target-group',
                                                         health_check_enabled=True,
                                                         health_check_interval_seconds=60,
                                                         health_check_timeout_seconds=30,
                                                         healthy_threshold_count=5,
                                                         unhealthy_threshold_count=5,
                                                         health_check_path='/health',
                                                         target_type='ip',
                                                         protocol='HTTP',
                                                         port=8080,
                                                         vpc_id=default_vpc.vpc_id
                                                         )

app_application_load_balancer = _elbv2.CfnLoadBalancer(self, "LB",
                                                                       subnets=default_vpc.select_subnets(
                                                                           subnet_type=_ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC).subnet_ids,
                                                                       name='app-lb',
                                                                       type='application',
                                                                       security_groups=[app_container.security_group_id],
                                                                       scheme='internet-facing')

app_service = _ecs.CfnService(self, 'Service',
                                              cluster=app_cluster.cluster_arn,
                                              task_definition=app_task_definition.attr_task_definition_arn,
                                              service_name='app-service',
                                              desired_count=1,
                                              launch_type=_ecs.LaunchType.FARGATE.name,
                                              network_configuration=_ecs.CfnService.NetworkConfigurationProperty(
                                                  awsvpc_configuration=_ecs.CfnService.AwsVpcConfigurationProperty(
                                                      subnets=default_vpc.select_subnets(
                                                          subnet_type=_ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC).subnet_ids,
                                                      # the properties below are optional
                                                      assign_public_ip="ENABLED",
                                                      security_groups=[
                                                          app_container.security_group_id]
                                                  )
                                              ),
                                              load_balancers=[_ecs.CfnService.LoadBalancerProperty(
                                                  container_port=8080,
                                                  container_name='app-broker',
                                                  target_group_arn=app_target_group.attr_target_group_arn
                                              )]
                                              )



app_listener = _elbv2.CfnListener(self, 'Listener', port=80, default_actions=[_elbv2.CfnListener.ActionProperty(type='forward',target_group_arn=app_target_group.attr_target_group_arn,
                                                                                                     )],
                                                  load_balancer_arn=
                                                   aws_cdk.Fn.select(0, infuse_ocpi_target_group.attr_load_balancer_arns))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ECS service takes care of registering and de-registering containers with the target group. In the `CfnService` you need to configure the `load_balancers` setting:

```
    load_balancers=[ecs.CfnService.LoadBalancerProperty(
        container_port=123,
        container_name="containerName",
        target_group_arn="targetGroupArn"
    )]
```

And to make that work you will also need to make the service depend on the listener:

```
app_service.node.addDependency(app_listener)
```

After doing this, the ECS service will automatically register the containers with the target group when new ECS Tasks are created by the service.

---

Also, as noted in the comments below, you were missing he `protocol` setting in the `CfnListener` code that you posted in your question.

Comment: I can't use the CfnLoadBalancer for that?

Comment: I still use the same ContainerDefinitionProperty as before, and I just make sure the name property of the ContainerDefinitionProperty and the name property of the LoadBalancerProperty are identical?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The container name property is optional, but it's not clear to me what the CDK would do if you didn't specify the name. To avoid any unwanted behavior I suggest setting the container name.

Comment: and also the load_balancer_name should be the name of the CfnLoadBalancer I defined, or that I don't need the CfnLoadBalancer and it will be created automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure you need the load balancer name, it is also optional. Target group is optional as well, but I don't see how it could work without specifying the target group. It's documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs/CfnService.html Please give it a try with the `container_port`, `container_name`, and `target_group_arn`

Comment: container_name and target_group_arn are also optional (container_port is not), but I guess that if I want to use a specific container and a specific target_group, I need to specify those fields, am I right?

Comment: I get "The target group with targetGroupArn <arn> does not have an associated load balancer."

Comment: It appears you haven't actually defined a load balancer in your CDK code yet? It's impossible for me to help you with that error without actually seeing all your CDK code.

Comment: I defined it, just didn't associate it with the target group (not sure how). I edited the question, I added all the code I have.

Comment: The load balancer listener associates the target group with the load balancer. Maybe you need to add the "load_balancer_name" configuration after all?

Comment: why would it ask target_group_arn but load_balancer_name and not load_balancer_arn? Anyway I get this error: "Invalid request provided: CreateService error: loadBalancerName and targetGroupArn cannot both be specified. You must specify either a loadBalancerName or a targetGroupArn."

Comment: It looks like your issue is the same as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53971873/the-target-group-does-not-have-an-associated-load-balancer and the fix is to add a cloudformation `DependsOn` to the ECS service, which in the CDK I believe looks like this:
`app_service.node.addDependency(app_listener)`

Comment: worked, thanks! I had to add 'protocol' to the CfnListener, and remove the 'load_balancer_name' from the CfnService. Then the last line of code is 'app_service.node.add_dependency(app_listener)' as you said. You can write this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @RonyTesler I've updated this answer.